# CRTP, templates, metaprogramming, forwarding and static member: a bug in g++ 4.8?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++

First, I am really sorry for the poor quality of this code, but I have already spent 1 hour to isolate the source of my problems and I do not have a shorter example than this.
So here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

template <class Crtp, class... Types>
struct Base
{
    template <
        unsigned int Index,
        class Type = typename std::tuple_element<Index, std::tuple<Types...> >::type
    >
    inline const Type& get() const {
        return std::get<Index>(data);
    }

    template <
        unsigned int Index,
        class Type = typename std::tuple_element<Index, std::tuple<Types...> >::type
    >
    inline Crtp& set(const Type& value) {
        std::get<Index>(data) = value; return static_cast<Crtp&>(*this);
    }

    std::tuple<Types...> data;
};

template <typename Type, unsigned int Size>
struct Derived : public Base<Derived<Type, Size>, std::array<Type, Size>>
{
    template <
        class... Args,
        class Template = decltype(std::declval<const Base<
            Derived<Type, Size>,
            std::array<Type, Size>
        >>().template get<0>(std::declval<Args>()...))
    >
    inline Template test(Args&&... args) const {
         return this->template get<0>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } 

    template <
        class... Args,
        class Template = decltype(std::declval<const Base<
           Derived<Type, Size>, 
           std::array<Type, Size>
        >>().template set<0>(std::declval<Args>()...))
    >
    inline Derived<Type, Size>& test(Args&&... args) {
        return this->template set<0>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } 

    static void check() {
         Derived<double, 3> derived;
         std::cout<<derived.test()[0]<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Derived<double, 3> derived;
    std::cout<<derived.test()[0]<<std::endl; // Working

    Derived<double, 3>::check(); // Not working: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘Derived<double, 3u>’ and ‘int’)
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation of what is done:
There is a `Base` class that takes a derived class (CRTP) and tuple types as template arguments. This base class has two members: one to `get` the n-th element of the `tuple`, the other to `set` the n-th element of the `tuple`. 
Then, there is a `Derived` class that inherits from the `Base` class and put a `std::array` in the tuple of the base class: consequently, the type of data of this derived class is : `std::tuple<std::array<Type, Size>> data`. This derived class has an overloaded function `test()` which calls the `get` or `set` function depending on its argument: `test()` will call `get()` but `test(std::array<double, 3>{1, 2, 3})` will call `set(std::array<double, 3>{1, 2, 3})`. Consequently `test()[0]` should return the first element of the array: it works in the `main()`, but it does not work in a static function.

I do not know what the compiler is trying to do, but apparently this is not working. 
I think that this is a bug in `g++ 4.8.1` (I have not tried other versions) but I wanted to be sure of that.

So here are my questions:

- Can you confirm this bug (and maybe find an explanation)?
- Do you have a shorter and less complicated example to illustrate the problem?

Comment: If you suspect a compiler bug, trying another compiler should be your first choice before posting on SO...

Comment: Do not compile under g++4.7.2 (tested on ideone), but compiles under clang++ 3.2.1...

Comment: I think GCC is correct. Your test function is const, so it will only be called when the object is const. It works on GCC if you add const to `Derived<double,3> derived` => `Derived<double,3> const derived` and it works.

Comment: If GCC is correct, then why this is working in the `main` and not in the `static` function ? Furthermore, I've just realized that `Derived<Type, Size>` derived seems to work. So is it a compiler bug or not ?

Comment: Looks like a bug in GCC to me. And occurs with GCC 4.9 (snapshot from 20130708) as well.

Comment: I reported the problem here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What the compiler is trying to do" is incorrectly performing overload resolution between the const and non-const overloads of `Derived::test` when called with no arguments inside `check()`. You can see by inserting

```
std::cout << typeid(decltype(derived.test())).name() << std::endl;
```

in both `check()` ("7DerivedIdLj3EE") and `main()` ("St5arrayIdLy3EE").

EDIT: A bit of investigation, alternately commenting out the const/nonconst test overload, shows that template deduction is not failing for the non-constant overload of `test` in `check()` as it should. The parameter pack `Args` is empty, so substitution failure should occur in the `decltype` expression that determines the return type of `set<0>` with no arguments.

While you're pondering why, I suggest you simplify your code to avoid it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

template <class Crtp, class... Types>
struct Base
{
    std::tuple<Types...> data;

    template <unsigned int Index>
    auto get() const -> decltype(std::get<Index>(data)) {
        return std::get<Index>(data);
    }

    template <unsigned int Index, typename T>
    Crtp& set(T&& value) {
        std::get<Index>(data) = std::forward<T>(value);
        return static_cast<Crtp&>(*this);
    }
};

template <typename Type, unsigned int Size>
struct Derived : public Base<Derived<Type, Size>, std::array<Type, Size>>
{
    auto test() const -> decltype(this->template get<0>()) {
        return this->template get<0>();
    }

    template <typename T>
    Derived& test(T&& value) {
        return this->template set<0>(std::forward<T>(value));
    }

    static void check() {
        Derived<double, 3> derived;
        std::cout << derived.test()[0] << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int, char*[])
{
    Derived<double, 3> derived;
    std::cout << derived.test()[0] << std::endl;
    Derived<double, 3>::check();
}
```

Comment: Suppose I should specify all the analysis I'm performing is with GCC 4.8.1.